# How to group JSON data using Javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, grouping

I have JSON data:

```
{"A1":"3","A2":"34","B1":"23","B2":"23","C1":"234","C2":"43",...}
```

I would like to group, or restructure it like so

```
var dataJson1 = {
 "A":{"A1":"3","A2":34}, 
 "B":{"B1":"23","B2":"23"}, 
 ...
}
```

AND

```
var dataJson2 = {
 "0":{"A1":"3", "B1":"23", ...}, 
 "1":{"A2":"34", "B2":"23", ...}
}
```

How can I group json data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just iterate your input object and build the other objects:

```js
var all = {
  "A1": "3",
  "A2": "34",
  "B1": "23",
  "B2": "23",
  "C1": "234",
  "C2": "43"
};

var dataJson1 = {};
var dataJson2 = {};
for (var k in all) {

  // data json 1
  var c = dataJson1[k[0]] = dataJson1[k[0]] || {};
  c[k] = all[k];

  // data json 2
  c = dataJson2[k[1] - 1] = dataJson2[k[1] - 1] || {};
  c[k] = all[k];
}

alert("JSON1: " + JSON.stringify(dataJson1));
alert("JSON2: " + JSON.stringify(dataJson2));
```